# React IntlProvider not update messages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-intl

I use React-intl to manage messages, this is my code:

Root.js

```
const Root = (props) => {
   return ( 
    <Router>
      <ConnectedIntlProvider>
        <WaitApplicationStartup component={App} />
      </ConnectedIntlProvider>
    </Router>)
}
```

ConnectedIntlProvider.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const {locale, messages} = state.locale;
  console.log(locale);
  console.log(messages);
  return {
    locale,
    messages
  };
}
const ConnectedIntlProvider = connect(mapStateToProps)(IntlProvider);
```

When I update message in `state`, the `message` in `ConnectedIntlProvider` is changed, but when I check in the child component such as `WaitApplicationStartUp`, it's still the ole one.